# DataContext being executed multiple times

Tags: xpages

Has anyone noticed an issue with datacontexts in xpages. In certain scenario a single xpage with multiple custom controls would result in the datacontext being evaluated 12 times during a single page load?? Does this happen with other dataSources as well?

Here is a simple example, which gets executed 3 times!!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
    xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex">
    <xp:this.dataContexts>
        <xp:dataContext var="doc1">
            <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:var doc:NotesDocument = database.createDocument();
doc.replaceItemValue("Form", "frmContact");
doc.replaceItemValue("fldFirstName", "test");
print("got here");
return doc;}]]></xp:this.value>
        </xp:dataContext>
    </xp:this.dataContexts>
    <xp:inputText id="inputText1" value="#{doc1.fldFirstName}"></xp:inputText>
</xp:view>
```

Should I not be using dataContexts in my application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And also watch out, if you are using partial refresh. Let's assume, you datacontext is in id B and you do a refresh on id A.  The datacontext in id B will also be refreshed. Also happens to all other data sources.

I have described this behaviour here http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/xpagesforum.nsf/topicThread.xsp?action=openDocument&documentId=56E9B8537DA50A90852579A6002EAC64#FA00DE3675A456C0852579AB005A1FF4

And there are also some hints about a PMR and a possible workaround for this.

Comment: Thanks Ulrich - I hope they fix this asap, I am using datacontexts everywhere in Xpages and custom controls!! The workaround doesn't really work with Domino objects, does it?

Answer (score 1):

Just like other controls on the page, the datacontext could be evaluated multiple times. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9413943/whats-the-benefits-of-using-data-context-in-xpages) for more information about the benefits of dataContexts. But in my opinion, from your code example, it could be faster to use a xp:data source but I'm not sure.

Comment: Many thanks Ferry - this is a very simple example, I am using this in a complex manner in other places, but the fact that this gets executed more than once is a concern! I don't know of a way to check how many times a xp:datasource is loaded, but I presume it might be doing the same thing!

Answer (score 1):

As with all other value bindings, if you change the # to a $, the value attribute of the dataContext may be requested multiple times, but the calculation to *determine* that value will only be executed once.

Comment: I am not sure this would apply here, you cannot really use computed on load ($) with domino objects, unless I am mistaken?

Comment: # vs. $ just determines how the property value is assigned. # means that a value binding object is created and associated with the property, so every time the property is accessed, it asks the value binding what it currently evaluates to. $ just means that when the object is instantiated, it evaluates the expression once, and assigns the result directly to the property's local value. So every time the property is accessed, it just returns that value.